# Question on terminology - equation with multiple =

Tags: logic, terminology, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have an equational derivation of $t = u$. There are two ways to prove this.

I can show it using a 'sequence of equations'
\begin{align*}
t_1 &= u_1\\
t_2 &= u_2\\
t &= u
\end{align*}

But I can also show it by
$$
t = \ldots = \ldots = u
$$
What would be a proper way to call such a derivation?

Comment: Provided that there is no issues with ambiguity, the second form will do as well, due to *transitivity* of $=$.

Comment: I would definitely call the first sequence a derivation ... or proof. But yes, I've wondered if that second one has a name as well ...